# Why windows 7 users see the vs code's website as not safe?

Tags: html

Why windows 7 users see the vs code's website as not safe?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxBm6.png

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the certificate authority is not recognised.

This is likely because [Windows 7 hasn't been supported for over a year](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-support-ended-on-january-14-2020-b75d4580-2cc7-895a-2c9c-1466d9a53962) so doesn't get updated lists of trusted certificate authorities.